# How do I hide /index.php? with wiki/topic?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I am running MediaWiki on my Apache server *(running on Ubuntu Server TLS, on VirtualBox)*, And I want everything to go like this:

`"10.0.1.87/wiki/Your_Topic"` instead of `"10.0.1.87/wiki/index.php?title=Your_Topic"`.

I do *not* want users to go to `"10.0.1.87/wiki/Your_Topic"` and be redirected ("redirected", being my basic understanding of it) to `"10.0.1.87/wiki/index.php?title=Your_Topic"`. I don't ever want them to have to see the `index.php`. I cannot seem to find anything on `.htaccess` files that would do this task, except for putting this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^wiki/(.+)" "http://10.0.1.87/wiki/index.php?title=$1" [P]
```

But when I open `"10.0.1.87/wiki/Home_Page"`, I get this error:

> "The requested URL /wiki/Home_Page was not found on this server."

.

Comment: Why are you using `P` flag?

Comment: In response to anuhhava:
This is the only thing close to what I want to accomplish. I have not found what I'm looking for yet.

Answer (score 0):

remove those double quotes

```
RewriteRule ^wiki/(.+) http://10.0.1.87/wiki/index.php?title=$1 [P]
```

Comment: When I do "10.0.1.87/wiki/" it gives me 403 (forbidden), and 404 when I do  "10.0.1.87/wiki/Home_Page". The 404 error is "The requested URL /wiki/Home_Page was not found on this server." I do believe this makes a loop in the proxy, because when it proxies, it proxies the proxy (if that makes sense).